# Grab table from another site

Tags: php, curl

I need to grab table from [this site](http://fc-stk-1914-samorin.futbalnet.sk/tim/17500) and display it in my site. Previously I used code below, but something has changed on source site (slightly different look) and code stopped working. Can anyone help me wit this case? Thank you in advance (sorry for bad english)

```
$ch = curl_init ("http://sfz.futbalnet.sk/sutaz/1302/?part=1831&round=38422");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$page = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match('#<table class="competition grey1 table table-condensed table-hover sort" [^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);

foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}

echo '<table id="grab" class="grabtable">';
echo $matches[1];
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit my answer and apologize for my mistake.

As you noticed, design (CSS classes) of the `<table>` changed.
Try this.

```
preg_match('#<table class="table full sort tablesorter tablesorter-default" [^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);
```

Comment: Hi ThinkTank, thank You for quick reply, I checked source of page, but I dont know how to, or whether it is even possible modify code i am using to work with div structure. It is possible?

Comment: My bad, I have been too quick ... didnt checked the good element. Table is stil table.